# Not able to connect remote floodlight controller to mininet

Tags: virtualbox, sdn, opendaylight, mininet

I am new to mininet and I was trying to build a mininet topology which uses a remote SDN controller.
I tried using floodlight as the remote controller. I installed it and ran it and it is running on "localhost:6653". But it is also running on 192.168.122.1:6653 (And I have no idea why). 
192.168.122.1 is my virbr0 interface's address. In my mininet VM which is in virtualbox i have two network adapters.

1. NAT
2. Host only adapter

And for host only adapter i have the following configuration.

> Adapter settings:
>   Ipv4 address: 192.168.56.1 and net mask: 255.255.255.0
>
> DHCP server settings: Sever ip= 192.168.56.100; net mask= 255.255.255.0; Lower bound Ip: 192.168.56.101; Upper bound Ip: 192.168.56.254

To avoid confusion i have added the screenshots as well.
[image: This is for adapter settings]

[image: This is for dhcp server settings]

I tried the following command to build my topology:

> sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=192.168.122.1,port=6653

I get the following response from mininet

> Unable to contact remote controller 192.168.122.1:6653

I have tried changing ip to 192.168.56.1 but that also didn't work.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per your setup, I guess FLC is running on Host OS and mininet is running in Oracle VM.

Your Host-Only network is useful if you are trying to reach something deployed in VM from your Host Os.

It will not work other way around. Here you want to access FLC running on Host inside your VM.

I would suggest using [Floodlight VM for Virtual Box](https://floodlight.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/floodlightcontroller/pages/8650780/Floodlight+VM#FloodlightVM-Download). It has mininet and FLC inbuild.

1. Once imported. Start VM.

   Credentials: `floodlight/floodlight`
2. Inside VM start FLC
3. Do `ifconfig` ithe n terminal and get `IP`
4. change to that IP in this

   sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=192.168.122.1,port=6653
5. and execute, all will work fine.
6. You can access FLC in Host using above IP

Comment: I changed the command a bit. I removed controller = remote and it worked. I was able to connec to flc oj my host machine. Again no idea how this worked.